# What is the expected performance of CloseableHttpClient, compared to Postman

Tags: java, httpclient

Get request using java HttpClient was taking more time than Postman(HttpClient -18972ms; Postman- around 17500ms)

So, I used CloseableHttpClient( took around 16250ms)

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
try    {
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) 
System.out.println(response);                                        
} finally {
response.close();    // <-- ensures reconnect
}
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Is this the best method to improve performance of rest requests in java - not just for get, but for post, delete, patch also ??
2. Requesting first time took much higher time , using HttpClient or CloseableHttpClient. Is there a way to improve this?
3. Is this the performance improvement expected while using CloseableHttpClient?? (16250ms vs 17500ms in Postman)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you test their performance? From how many executions did you take the average from?

Comment: For HttpClient and CloseableHttpResponse, I took new Date().getTime() before and after  httpClient.execute(httpGet), and took the difference.

I took the average of 5 executions

Comment: Well 5 is a pretty low amount. Take 100 executions and you'll have more reliable results to compare. The network will always be the bottleneck here, not the http client.

Comment: Okay.
But is there a better option than CloseableHttpClient ?

Comment: Better how? I told you the bottleneck is the network. You'd have to have a heavy load to distinguish differences (if any) between the clients.